# Cannot execute get from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I need execute get after timeout so I do

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.get("final.jsp");
}, 600);
```

But it does not execute at all.

Then I do next

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.get("appname/final.jsp");
}, 600);
```

It executes and can not find a path which is wrong

```
http://localhost:8080/appname/appname/final.jsp
```

So how can I actually make a `get` after delay?

Comment: What is your exact question?  You're calling `$.get()` and not doing anything with the result.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  If the path is wrong, then either fix the relative path or switch to an absolute path starting with `/`.  If you want help with the relative path, you have to tell us what the actual URL should be and what the URL is of the current page.  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with a delay.

Comment: @jfriend00 The exact question is how to make a GET request - is it so complicated?

Comment: this url is legal `http://localhost:8080/grammar/` or `http://localhost:8080/grammar/final.jsp` or `http://localhost:8080/grammar/hello`

Comment: You just listed three URLs.  Which one are you actually trying to use `$.get()` with?  What's so complicated is that you don't say what URL you are actually trying to load and you don't say what the problem is.  `$.get()` works just fine no matter where you put it if you pass it the right arguments.  Next time, you may not want to make jest of people that don't understand your question.  Better to just explain what they ask about so they can help you.  What's obvious to you is not always so obvious to people reading your writing.

Comment: @jfriend00  well. it seems to me clear about the question. all i need is open the url in browser from js code i.e. to do `get request`. any of those url are working so you can use those which looks best. i do not know how to explaine it clearly...

Comment: It doesn't matter what seems clear to you.  It matters what seems clear to the people that are trying to help you.  Nowhere in your question does it say you're trying to open the page.  `$.get()` does an ajax call, it doesn't open a page in the browser.  See what I added to my answer below about opening a page in the browser.

Comment: @furry - "i do not know how to explaine it clearly." is exactly the point being made to you. You are NOT asking a question in a way that other people can understand. Given the answer you accepted all the stuff about the delay had nothing to do with your actual question. I suggest you were not at all clear in your own mind about what your question was. It is very clear you were not clear in asking it in a way others can understand. Learning how to ask good questions is a skill you should work on to help you in many aspects of life. It is something you should work on and welcome feedback about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL you are trying to use `$.get()` with is this (which I'm just guessing because you haven't been entirely clear about that):

```
http://localhost:8080/grammar/final.jsp
```

Then, use:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.get("/grammar/final.jsp").then(function(result) {
        // process result here
    });
}, 600);
```

If you're actually trying to retrieve content with that Ajax call, then you will need to do something with the result of the ajax call.

---

If you're trying to open the URL in the browser (which your question does not actually say), then you don't use `$.get()` because that's an Ajax call.  Instead, you would want to use either this:

```
// change current window to new URL
window.location = "http://localhost:8080/grammar/final.jsp";
```

or this:

```
// open new window (will probably get blocked by pop-up blocker)
// if done from setTimeout()
window.open("http://localhost:8080/grammar/final.jsp");
```